Does kernel sends write requests in order to backend device
When the application is sequentially writing data to a file, how does kernel sends it to the actual backend device (disk/fuse-based device). Does it maintain the order or not? This is without o-direct & writeback cache enabled.
More context:
For a fuse based backend i have always seen the requests comes in order if the application writes in sequence from starting offset to end. But if we write at random offsets or in reverse order, the application write order is not maintained. Want to understand how kernel sends requests to backend device.

You can use my example for a simple kernel block device and debug whatever the kernel is doing on writes https://orenkishon.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/stackbd-stacking-a-block-device-over-another-block-device/

For a block device, the I/O scheduler could re-order the requests. For a spinning rust HDD it may be beneficial to write blocks out of order to reduce head movement.
